# How to get the JSON from external server

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, jsonp

thanks in advance!

I am trying to do a Jquery.ajax() to get the JSON from this link:
[API](http://api.9292.nl/0.1/locations/station-amsterdam-centraal/departure-times?lang=nl-NL).

 This is the code I use:
`$.ajax({
        url : "https://api.9292.nl/0.1/locations/station-amsterdam-centraal/departure-times?lang=nl-NL",
        dataType: "json",
        success:function(data)
        {
            console.log('gelukt');
        },
        errror: function (data) {
            console.log(data);
        }
    });`

But it gives the error "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present", so i tried to set dataType to 'jsonp', but then a error shows up  with:  
'Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :'
Anyone got an idea, how to get the JSON from that API?

You would help me a lot!

Thanks

Comment: You need to learn about CORS or JSONP

Comment: If they do not support CORS/JSONP you are not going to get it without a proxy.

Answer (score 0):

Read about **JSONP** [here](http://json-p.org/) or [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP), most probably you need to pass a callback parameter into query.